# Using NuGet with multiple development pipelines best practices?

Tags: version-control, nuget, version, controls

We're implementing NuGet (albeit slowly) - but we've run into an issue, and I'm trying to not abandon NuGet.

Our new development process has a DEV environment with multiple pipelines being worked on.  We need a way to isolate code changes to a single pipeline.

Right now, if Branch 1 publishes a change to NuGet, Branch 2 might pull it in, but it's incompatible with (let's say) the database in Branch 2.

So my first thought, is to separate the Majors by branch - Branch 1 = 1.*.*, Branch 2 = 2.*.*, etc.  This feels... wrong, though.

Ok, well, the Minor feels more correct - Branch 1 = v1.1.*, Branch 2 = v1.2.*, but then what about when Branch 1 adds a new feature, necessitating Branch 1 = v1.2?  Now we have conflicts with Branch 2's v1.2.*

I'm considering the idea of separate Feeds per pipeline, then when we go to UAT, we take that code, and auto-increment the Minor in the nuspec file, and push that to the 'mainline' feed with Symbols, and in Release mode when UAT passes...

Comment: It is never an obligation to update a package, so one project could use an "old" version. Do you use a package interface design that is backwards compatible?

Comment: Correct - the issue is as new features are added separately in each pipeline, we don't want those stepping on each other while in the pipelines.  In other words, add a feature in PIpeline1 = package-1.1.0, add a feature in Pipeline2 = package-1.1.0, how would we know which pipeline is using which package?

Comment: Separate Feeds per pipeline with a proper SemVer and prerelase versions seems like a better idea. Also maybe splitting the packages to limit stepping on each others toes is an option?